# Angular modules cant see module, imported in main module

Tags: angular, module

Im using TranslateModule, importing him in AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppCommonModule } from "./AppCommon/app-common.module";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { AuthModule} from "./auth/auth.module";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule,
    AppCommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      defaultLanguage: 'en'
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have children modules: AuthModule, AppCommonModule.
Components in children modules dont see TranslatePipe.

AuthModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { Route, RouterLink } from "@angular/router";
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

export const authRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, title: 'Login' },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, title: 'Register' }
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterLink,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

AppCommonModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from "./navbar/navbar.component";
import { RouterLink } from "@angular/router";
import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page/main-page.component';
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";
import { NotificationComponent } from './notification/notification.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainPageComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    FooterComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainPageComponent,
    NotificationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 3000,
      preventDuplicates: true,
      maxOpened: 3,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
      toastComponent: NotificationComponent,
      toastClass: ""
    }),
    RouterLink,
  ]
})
export class AppCommonModule { }
```

Errors:
Error: src/app/auth/register/register.component.html:63:63 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.

I've tried to regenerate new main module, new children modules, remove and install node_modules, but (((
[source code](https://github.com/mrlaige04/TripSync/tree/master/src/ClientApp/src)

Answer (score 0):

Remove Import of TranslateModule from app.module.ts and add your import of TranslateModule in app-common.module.ts and auth.module.ts. It will work fine.

Rather than importing module in app module import in the module where you are using it.